# using caret ^ with imagemagick on m1 mac, zsh: no matches found

Tags: imagemagick, zsh

Using ImageMagick on m1 mac, how can this code:

```
convert input.jpg -scale 3000x3000^ -gravity center -extent 3000x3000 output.jpg
```

be run without getting this error:

```
zsh: no matches found: 3000x3000^
```

I tried putting single and double quotes in a number of places but each had its own error.

Comment: `^` is a glob character in `zsh`, and unlike `bash`, failed glob expansion produces an error, rather than leaving the word as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a backslash.

```
convert input.jpg -scale 3000x3000\^ -gravity center -extent 3000x3000 output.jpg
```

Comment: You can equally use `-scale '3000x3000^'`